# Apply XSLT stylesheet to Amazon Product Advertising API XML output

Tags: php, xml, api, xslt, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am trying to apply my XSLT stylesheet to Amazon API xml output and display a movie title on the page

This is my XSLT file (amazon.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title" />
        </root>
        </xml>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <xsl:text>Movie title</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is Amazon API XML output:

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
   <OperationRequest>
       <HTTPHeaders>
          <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22"/>
       </HTTPHeaders>
       <RequestId>a1138e89-4335-4650-80f2-641e3c58b623</RequestId>
       <Arguments>
    <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup"/>
    <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
    <Argument Name="Signature" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
    <Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B004LWZWGK"/>
    <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2013-03-21T13:56:55.000Z"/>
    <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Small"/>
       </Arguments>
       <RequestProcessingTime>0.0189320000000000</RequestProcessingTime>
       </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
      <Item>
         <ItemAttributes>
           <Title>
            The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
           </Title>
         </ItemAttributes>
      </Item>
    </Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

I have found and used the following PHP code to search for the movie title and display it on the page. However, it
only displays it in plain text. I would like to apply an XSLT style to it but I don't know how to properly include it in my php code.

If XSLT was used correctly, it would display "Movie title" right above the actual title.

*amazon.php*

```
include('aws_signed_request.php');

$public_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$private_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$associate_tag = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// generate signed URL
$request = aws_signed_request('co.uk', array(
        'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
        'ItemId' => 'B004LWZWGK',
        'ResponseGroup' => 'Small'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag);

// do request (you could also use curl etc.)
$response = @file_get_contents($request);
if ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "Request failed.\n";
} else {

    // parse XML
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('amazon.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($response);
    $transform = $proc->transformToXML($doc);
    $pxml = simplexml_load_string($transform);

    if ($pxml === FALSE) {
        echo "Response could not be parsed.\n";
    } else {
        if (isset($pxml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title)) {
            echo $pxml->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title, "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

*aws_signed_request.php*

```
function aws_signed_request($region, $params, $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag=NULL, $version='2011-08-01')
{    
    /*
    Parameters:
        $region - the Amazon(r) region (ca,com,co.uk,de,fr,co.jp)
        $params - an array of parameters, eg. array("Operation"=>"ItemLookup",
                        "ItemId"=>"B000X9FLKM", "ResponseGroup"=>"Small")
        $public_key - your "Access Key ID"
        $private_key - your "Secret Access Key"
        $version (optional)
    */

    // some paramters
    $method = 'GET';
    $host = 'webservices.amazon.'.$region;
    $uri = '/onca/xml';

    // additional parameters
    $params['Service'] = 'AWSECommerceService';
    $params['AWSAccessKeyId'] = $public_key;
    // GMT timestamp
    $params['Timestamp'] = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    // API version
    $params['Version'] = $version;
    if ($associate_tag !== NULL) {
        $params['AssociateTag'] = $associate_tag;
    }

    // sort the parameters
    ksort($params);

    // create the canonicalized query
    $canonicalized_query = array();
    foreach ($params as $param=>$value)
    {
        $param = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($param));
        $value = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($value));
        $canonicalized_query[] = $param.'='.$value;
    }
    $canonicalized_query = implode('&', $canonicalized_query);

    // create the string to sign
    $string_to_sign = $method."\n".$host."\n".$uri."\n".$canonicalized_query;

    // calculate HMAC with SHA256 and base64-encoding
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $private_key, TRUE));

    // encode the signature for the request
    $signature = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($signature));

    // create request
    $request = 'http://'.$host.$uri.'?'.$canonicalized_query.'&Signature='.$signature;

    return $request;
}
```

I know it's a lot of code, but everything in PHP works perfectly fine and I do get a movie title displayed on the page. I just want to apply my XSLT stylesheet to it as well. I am very new to PHP and cannot figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: If you want to transform the XML and display it in a browser, you need to transform it into HTML. A browser doesn't know what to do with `<xml><root></root></xml>` (and `xml` is not a legal element name either).

Comment: thanks for your reply, JLRishe. But what would I use instead of <xml> and <root>? I just want to get to "ItemLookupResponse/Items/Item/ItemAttributes/Title" and then apply some style to the "Title" element. How would I do it in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question from the comments, here is how you could generate an HTML page from that input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
         exclude-result-prefixes="aws">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <h1>
      <xsl:text>Movie Title</xsl:text>
    </h1>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />    
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Movie Title</h1>
          The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
        </body>
</html>
```

If you just want to generate an HTML snipped to add to a larger page that you are displaying, you could just use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
         exclude-result-prefixes="aws">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <div>
      <h1>
        <xsl:text>Movie Title</xsl:text>
      </h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces:

```
<h1>Movie Title</h1>
      The Dark Knight Rises (Blu-ray/DVD Combo+UltraViolet Digital Copy)
```

Comment: I have used the second solution that you've provided, JLRishe. I get the following two warnings on the php page: 1) "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in myservername/amazon.php on line 35 Warning: simplexml_load_string():" 2) "Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in myservername/amazon.php on line 35 Response could not be parsed." I do get the "Movie title" and the actual title displayed on the page, but I also get these warnings. any ideas? thank you for your help.

Comment: That's probably happening because the result doesn't have a single root element. I don't think there's really a need to use `simplexml_load_string()` on the result, but if you want to, I think the modification I've just made above, to wrap the content in a `div`, should fix that warning.

Comment: JLRishe, the warning has disappeared completely, but now the page is completely blank and does not display anything at all. Would it have something to do with "transformToXML" solution that Chris has provided earlier? I've updated my amazon.php with his solution, so maybe there is something missing there? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: After this line: `$transform = $proc->transformToXML($doc);` please just try `echo $transform;`. I don't think the stuff after that line is necessary.

Comment: yes! everything works perfectly now. You have no idea how long I've been trying to get this amazon api to work properly. JLRiche, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have created the processor and imported the stylesheet on lines 6 & 7 in `amazon.php` but you still need to apply it using [`XSLTProcessor::transformToXML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php)

```
// parse XML
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML($response);
$transform = $proc->transformToXML($doc);
$pxml = simplexml_load_string($transform);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Chris. I've used your solution, but now the page does not display anything at all. I've updated my amazon.php code above. So maybe if you can have a look at it and point out a mistake that I've made. I'm very new to php. thank you